# setattr() with eval() not working as expected

Tags: python

Here's what I'm trying to do:

### In `file_execed.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def foo():
    return True

def bar():
    return foo()
```

### In `file_main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import module_to_add_to

exec_results = {}
execfile("file_execed.py", globals(), exec_results)

# Attach objects created by exec to module_to_add_to
for k, v in exec_results.iteritems():
    setattr(module_to_add_to, k, v)

module_to_add_to.call()
```

### And finally, in `module_to_add_to.py`:

The following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def call():
    eval("foo()", globals(), {})
```

But not this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def call():
    eval("bar()", globals(), {})
```

`NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined`

Why is it that `foo()` is visible when eval'ed directly from `module_to_add_to.py` but not when called from an eval'ed `bar()`?

Comment: I tried, but both of your code doesn't work. They're called on "import module_to_add_to". And surely, we don't have foo() or bar() defined, so they're all failed.

Comment: @PhuongNguyen ah I see, in an effort to make it more readable, I ended up over-simplifying it. Fixed it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your code in `file_main.py`

```
execfile("file_execed.py", globals(), exec_results)
```

This line creates two functions named `foo`, `bar` and put them into the dict `exec_results`. When these functions are created, their global state (result of globals()) is what we put on the second parameter of `execfile` command, in this case it's the global state of `file_main.py` (remember that when a function is defined in a module, it's set into the `locals()` of that module, not `globals()`)

```
# Attach objects created by exec to module_to_add_to
for k, v in exec_results.iteritems():
    setattr(module_to_add_to, k, v)
```

The two functions `foo`, `bar` above are added to the module `module_to_add_to`.

```
module_to_add_to.call()
```

The function `bar` above is called, when it's called, as what stated above, its global state is the global state of `file_main.py`, so let's check what we have in the global state of `file_main.py` by adding this line above `module_to_add_to.call()`:

```
print(globals().keys())
```

And we get:

```
['exec_results', '__builtins__', '__file__', 'module_to_add_to', '__package__', 'v', '__name__', '__doc__', 'k']
```

There's no `foo` or `bar` here, so that's why you got the `NameError` exception.

You can try modifying your code as below and it will work:

```
# Attach objects created by exec to module_to_add_to
for k, v in exec_results.iteritems():
    setattr(module_to_add_to, k, v)
    globals()[k] = v
```

Hope this helps.